# Convert date to eastern time zone with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting data back from the server like this:

```
'2015-03-05T16:51:56+00:00'
```

Using Angular, I'd like to display this date/time as an Eastern Time date. Is there a way to specify a different timezone with Angular? I'm doing something like:

```
{{ myDate | date: 'medium' }}
```

Which gives back:

```
Mar 5, 2015 11:51:56 AM
```

But I'd like it to display as:

```
Mar 5, 2015 4:51:56 PM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the angularJS [`dateFilter` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

> `timezone` *(optional)* **string**
>
> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used.

So try:

```
{{ myDate | date: 'medium' : -0500 }}
```

Comment: it seems, you are missing, Single quote '' in time zone format. taken from angular js docs. Timezone to be used for formatting. "It understands UTC/GMT and the continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used."

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the `date` filter in [HTML template binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) since 1.3 allows for an optional `timezone` field:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

However, 1.3 only supports the **UTC** timeszone.

> Timezone to be used for formatting. Right now, only 'UTC' is
>   supported. If not specified, the timezone of the browser will be used

In the 1.4 beta, it now supports more than just **UTC**:

> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the
>   continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a
>   time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of
>   the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser
>   will be used.

You could specify the timezone or the offset to use:

```
{{ myDate | date: 'medium' | timezone: '+0430'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. I tried several option but at last the following code gave the result that I want.

{{ date_expression | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy': '+0900'}}