# I want to convert ngComboDatePicker date into yyyy-mmm-dd format

Tags: angularjs

I am using ngComboDatePicker for date of birth. I am getting date in this format:

```
dateOfBirth:Wed Jan 03 1940 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

this I want to convert into `yyyy-mmm-dd` format, html.

```
<ng-combo-date-picker ng-model="user.dateOfBirth" ng-placeholder="YYYY,MMM,DD" ng-min-date="{{ min.toString() }}" ng-max-date="{{ max.toString() }}"></ng-combo-date-picker>.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to eastern time zone with Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883472/convert-date-to-eastern-time-zone-with-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user.dateOfBirth = $filter('date')(user.dateOfBirth.getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd");